# Genymotion-ARM-Translation.zip is not working on android L

Tags: android, arm, genymotion

I run my app on Android L virtual machine on Genymotion and find error here `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS`.

I have installed `Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip` but it fails on android L.This zip is working for genymition virtual machine below android Lolipop ,such as android 4.4,4.3. What can I do to run app without x86 libs on android L on genymotion ,I found https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145 ,but it still does not work.Can anyone help? thank you

Comment: thank Mohit Singh for help editing